# Highcharts Treemap

Tags: javascript, css, angular, highcharts, treemap

I am currently building a treemap using highcharts. I have a few categories, and each category has a numerical value indicating how many programs it has inside. What I want to do is have a treemap in the "squarified" style with a box for each category.

The issue I'm running into is that the font size handling highcharts has is abysmal. I'm looking to have the text be large for the larger boxes, and small for the smaller boxes. I cannot seem to figure it out.

I've tried scaling the font size to the value, but sometimes boxes of a large value are really thin, so that falls apart.

I have access to the dimensions of the box, and can give the chart a datalabel formatter function. So I've tried rendering text to a canvas at a certain size, seeing if it is within the bounds or too small, and adjusting by 1 pixel from there, but it still did not work. I actually don't know why this one failed but I messed around with it for *a while* but has no success.

I've read the documentation and searched for other answers online but no one seems to have done this before. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Noah, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o0ckadbs/

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek, that example already shows the problem I'm having. The bottom left and bottom middle boxes, labeled peter and anne, have font sized appropriately to their box. However, the top left box, labeled rick, is larger but has the same size font. I am unable to find any way to make font scale with the size of the box. If I make the default size bigger, the font in the rick box would be sized appropriately, but the peter and anne boxes' font would be either hidden due to overflow, or have ugly overflowing text (depending on a setting)

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatter function for data labels and make font size depending on point value.

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        levels: [{
            ...
        }, {
            level: 2,
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<span style="font-size:' + (10 + this.point.value) + 'px">' + this.key + '</span>'
                }
            }
        }],
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8e7b6ak0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.levels.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. While the squarified algorithm does it's best, it's not perfect, and results in boxes with weird aspect ratios, for which this method fails. A very large value can end up with a wide but short box.

Comment: Hi @Noah, You can also use a box height to calculate font size, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zfh8bqn7/